# Nativescript - cannot run android on device

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I used to be able to run on android and all of a sudden I am getting this error (see below).

The only thing I recall changing is downgrading "nativescript-ui-listview" to "^7.1.0" and "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer" to "~7.0.0" because it otherwise breaks on ios 12.

```
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Project successfully prepared (android)
Installing on device f180a829...
More than one .apk found in /Users/manuelmaestrini/Programming/spiio-development/spiiomobile/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk directory. Using the last one produced from build.
Successfully installed on device with identifier 'f180a829'.
Application com.spiio.mobile is not running on device f180a829.
This issue may be caused by:
        * crash at startup (try `tns debug android --debug-brk` to check why it crashes)
        * different application identifier in your package.json and in your gradle files (check your identifier in `package.json` and in all *.gradle files in your App_Resources directory)
        * device is locked
        * manual closing of the application
Unable to apply changes on device: f180a829. Error is: Application com.spiio.mobile is not running.
```

Any idea what might be? I tried to do --clean, remove node_modules, hooks, platforms, uninstall and reinstall webpack etc but no luck...

Comment: Try with `"nativescript-ui-listview": "^8.2.0"` and `"nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^7.0.4"`. It works fine for me.

Comment: delete and re-add your android platform